# show image in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Before starting use https my application it worked with http request. Everything is worked fine. But when I decided to change all url to https I have one unsolved problem. I can't show images in webview it doesn't show nothing. What should I do here to show images using https request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading https url shows blank page because you should decide if your app wants to proceed to an untrusted web site via a WebView. You can set this by overriding onReceivedSslError method in WebViewClient. I tested your image and it shows proper image.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

...

private class CustomViewClient extends WebViewClient
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
   }
}
```

However, this only works from Android 2.2(Froyo). For Android version below 2.2, a public API is not provided.